# Bind a key to a GTK application, without removing the existing one

Tags: c, gtk

I am making a small graphical program in C, using gtk.

I managed to create a keyboard shortcut, when I press the escap button, the application exit :

```
gboolean on_key_press (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data){
    switch(event->keyval){
        case GDK_Escape:
            gtk_main_quit();
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

When I create the GUI, I have this code to detect keypress :

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "key_press_event", G_CALLBACK(on_key_press), pCtxt);
```

The problem is, it disable any kind of interaction, like using the TAB key to choose a button, or even entering text into a gtk_entry.

How can I have keyboard shortcuts, without destroying the default behavior for keypress events ?

Comment: You didn't read my whole question. "How can I have keyboard shortcuts, without destroying the default behavior for keypress events ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your event handler `return FALSE;` to propagate the event further. As the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) says:

> Return `TRUE` to stop other handlers from being invoked for the event. `FALSE` to propagate the event further.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks you !